# svctraceviewer for windows server 2003

Tags: wcf, debugging, windows-server-2003

I am trying to get the svctraceviewer installed on windows server 2003. I found that it's part of the Windows SDK which is of huge size. Moreover, i wouldn't want install Windows SDK on a server unless it's a hot patch. Is there a way to download or copy the tool separately(probably from windows vista)?

Is there an alternative tool that can be downloaded with reasonable size?

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your right, you probably don't want to push the Windows SDK to all of your servers! :)  However, the SvcTraceViewer will run just fine by itself.

We copy it, and some other 'standard' tools to our servers to aid operators/developers in debugging those environments if absolutely necessary.

I don't know of any alternative tools that function as well as it does for specifically reviewing WCF/WF trace logs, but a protocol analyzer (NetMon, Wireshark) will let you see the network traffic.  This doesn't help you if your problem is not at the wire level though!

Good Luck!